# Can't install Google App Engine tools for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, plugins

I tried to install the `GAE` tools for Android and the plugin but I received this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google App Engine Tools for Android 2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r37)
  Missing requirement: com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android 2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r37 requires 'bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 12.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google App Engine Tools for Android 2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r37)
    To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android [2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r37]
```

Has anyone else received this?

Comment: if you have got the solution then please tell me, because i am also getting the same problem

Comment: I tried later and it worked.  Looks like it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually caused by your proxy configuration. This error appears to me while trying to download from a network that blocked the content.